# cannot invoke a method on the primitive type double

Tags: java

I had taken an intro java class awhile back, trying to create a simple code for calculating grades using arrays. I'm running into this error:

```
File: C:\Users\Owner\CS-121\GradeDriver.java  [line: 18]
Error: Cannot invoke getPoint() on the primitive type double
```

class and driver are as follows:

```
public class Grade{
    private double point;

    public Grade(double x){
        point = x; 
    }

    public double getPoint(){
        return point; 
    }
}


public class GradeDriver{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double score;
        double text = 0;
        double eoc = 0;
        double prog = 0;
        double mid = 0;
        double fin = 0;
        double[] textWork = {1.0,4.0,5.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,3.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,
                             9.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,5.0,3.0,5.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,
                             7.0,3.0,8.0,7.0,6.0,1.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,
                             4.0,2.0,3.0,8.0,1.0};
        double[] eocWork = {10.0,34.0,44.0,36.0,40.0,50.0,30.0,38.0,
                            14.0,40.0,12.0,26.0};
        double[] progWork = {10.0,10.0,5.0,7.0,7.0,9.0,10.0};
        double[] midTerm = {83.0};
        double[] finTerm = {68.0};

        for(int j = 0; j < textWork.length; j++){
            text = text + textWork[j].getPoint(); 
        }
        text = (text/132.0)*7.0;

        for(int j = 0; j < eocWork.length; j++){
            eoc = eoc + eocWork[j].getPoint(); 
        }
        eoc = (eoc/384.0)*15.0;

        for(int j = 0; j < progWork.length; j++){
            prog = prog + progWork[j].getPoint(); 
        }
        prog = (prog/70.0)*28.0;

        for(int j = 0; j < midTerm.length; j++){
            mid = mid + midTerm[j].getPoint(); 
        }
        mid = mid*0.15;

        for(int j = 0; j < finTerm.length; j++){
            fin = fin + finTerm[j].getPoint(); 
        }
        fin = fin*0.35;

        score = fin + mid + prog + eoc + text;
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well things like `textWork[j]` are doubles, and you're trying to call a method on them - it's what the error message says. If they were instances of class `Grade` then you could call `getPoint()` on them, but they're not.

Comment: And please fix the hideous formatting.

Comment: `textWork[j].getPoint(); ` What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: I was trying to total up points from each section, and add values from each to print out a final numerical grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these loops:

```
for(int j = 0; j < textWork.length; j++) {
    text = text + textWork[j].getPoint();
}
```

to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < textWork.length; j++) {
    text = text + textWork[j];
}
```

You array contain doubles so by calling the `array[i]` you are calling the value at the index `i`

Furthermore methods can be called upon instances of the class containing them. In that case you could call the `getPoint()` method in an instance of the class Grade. For example:

```
Grade grade = new Grade(5.5);
grade.getPoint();
```

Instead you are calling it on each value of your array which is not of type `Grade` but of type double. Hence the problem

Also all those for loops do basically the same thing so it would be much better if you had a single method instead of so much duplicate code

e.g.

```
double sum(double[] array) {
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result += array[i];
    }
}
```

and then call the method for all your array and store in a variable

```
text = (sum(textWork)/132.0)*7.0;
```

and so on.